# How do I decrease sql query execution time in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have query as

```
select i.shipping_charges, i.shipping_carrier, i.shipping_method, 
       i.tracking_number, i.origin_zip_code, i.origin_city, 
       i.origin_country, i.weight_value, i.weight_unit, 
       i.delivery_date, i.shipping_date, i.shipping_description, 
       i.delivery_zip_code, i.delivery_street_add, i.item_id, 
       i.start_at, i.end_at, i.id 
from (items it 
      left join item_shipping_details i on it.id = i.item_id) 
left join users u on u.id = it.alert_user_id 
where it.user_id=4 AND i.id in (35,602,1175,1176,1177,604,1178,1174,
                                1165,1179,930,1160,917,914,925,909,920,1147,910)  
                   AND (it.alert_user_id is null OR u.user_type in (2,3))  
                   AND (it.outbound != true OR it.outbound is null)
```

It takes 8ms in postgresql to run.
Please tell any other alternative solution to this?

Comment: Do you want it to run longer or what?

Comment: I think he wants to REDUCE the exec time, not increase lol

Comment: yes i want to decrease its execution time.

Comment: How about an explain plan to see what the planner is actually doing?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things were odd or straight out nonsensical about your query.

- Primary table in the `FROM` list was `items`, but you don't have a single column of it in the `SELECT` list  main table. The way you had it, it would at best add a bunch of rows with only NULL values, while confusing the query planner. You want neither of that.
  I reversed the order and made `item_shipping_details` the primary table. This will be *much* faster.
- The `LEFT JOIN` between `items` and `item_shipping_details` was contradictory, because additional clauses require a row from both tables anyway. Simplified to plain `JOIN`.
  <sup>Also makes the order of appearance of the first two tables irrelevant again.</sup>
- Removed the brackets around the first JOIN, as that served no purpose.
- Simplified `(it.outbound != true OR it.outbound is null)` to `it.outbound IS NOT TRUE`

```
SELECT i.shipping_charges, i.shipping_carrier, i.shipping_method, 
       i.tracking_number, i.origin_zip_code, i.origin_city, 
       i.origin_country, i.weight_value, i.weight_unit, 
       i.delivery_date, i.shipping_date, i.shipping_description, 
       i.delivery_zip_code, i.delivery_street_add, i.item_id, 
       i.start_at, i.end_at, i.id 
FROM   item_shipping_details i
JOIN   items it ON it.id = i.item_id
LEFT   JOIN users u on u.id = it.alert_user_id 
WHERE  i.id IN (35,602,1175,1176,1177,604,1178,1174,1165,1179,
                930,1160,917,914,925,909,920,1147,910)
AND    it.user_id = 4
AND    it.outbound IS NOT TRUE
AND   (it.alert_user_id IS NULL OR u.user_type IN (2,3))
```

Should considerably increase <strike>execution time</strike> ... performance. :)

Comment: I'd love for User123 to provide explain plans for the before and after so we can learn how the query change impacted the explain plan.

Comment: @StarShip3000: Yup, that would be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant decrease query execution time, turning on indexing for the appropriate columns can greatly speed up result retrieval.

Comment: What kind of data types are you using for these fields, and have you considered breaking up your items table into a few smaller tables?

Comment: Actually i got to know that if we are having 2 tables then the order of using 2 tables also matters in exec time. Is this really a parameter to be considered?

Comment: 80% fields have varchar as a datatype and other are boolean and integer

Comment: It can. See, depending on how you break up and structure your tables, the speed of your queries will be affected. Storing everything in one giant table doesn't necessarily make it faster because you don't need to perform an inner join.

Comment: Hmm. Your data types do not look particularly odd, but more data would be required for a better assessment. At this point, you might want to use the "EXPLAIN" SQL keyword for better performance tuning, or possibly better hardware. Here is a link to some general strategies: http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

THIS PART OF YOUR QUERY IS TAKING TIME

```
IN (35,602,1175,1176,1177,604,1178,1174,1165,1179,
            930,1160,917,914,925,909,920,1147,910)
```

YES "Subqueries" there are many ways:

1. Use JOIN() and less INCLUDE() in association.
2. Try to avoid subqueries and find([array])
3. Use cache

There may be more better options you may find below in rails doc
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html